# Airflow in my specific case

Tags: fan, case

I have this https://www.gamemaxpc.com/product/showproduct.php?id=672 computer case (GameMax Dark Ranger) with 1 back fan slot and two top fan slots. I have 3 great fans with about 1800 spins per minute. How should I put them?

Comment: Most cases you want fans pushing air out of the case.

Comment: @Moab Surely with 3 fans you want 1 pulling in and 2 pushing out? If 3 are pushing out where is the fresh are coming in from?

Comment: In the linked case's.. ermm… case - through any air-gaps. It's the typical zero-airflow design, too much left to chance, no clear path. Even the PSU is expected to drag air through the carpet. The filters seem to be on the outflow not the inflow. It's the usual never saw a CFD designer mess. If it were mine, I'd put one in the front top, one in the rear top& one in the 'roof'. I'd also make sure it's mounted on a wooden or tiled floor, not a carpet.

Comment: I'd probably re-jig the filter to the front too, on the outside - but there's no image showing what that front wall looks like without the front cover, so without that, it's anyone's guess. [If we can have some pictures showing the bare-bones case, I'll change this to an answer.]

Comment: @DavidPostill most cases have plenty of vents for pulling in air.

Comment: @Tetsujin well it's an super cheap small case because I'm on a very low budget and there is no front cover its xd I can only remove side panels